# How TXT file write and clean

Tags: android, text

i wANT write one value example 'm' to txt file and next time i want to write new value before write clean all value in txt and new write.

example :

i save 'm' write in m.txt next time write in txt file delete valaue 'm' in txt file and write new value example 'n'

Comment: This question is beyond confusing.

Answer (score 1):

(any platform) Delete previous file (if it exists) and create it again.

Comment: every time? can't clean value in file ?!!

Comment: You could override the value, if you do not use "append", but you can not delete it. Or you can "truncate" the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use append and only the write flag then it will rewrite the file every time. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) for how to write files to storage in Android.

Comment: @user2654276 Your question is extremely confusing. If you don't want m to appear anymore, DON'T use append.